# How do I identify bank deposits by Valve for Steam revenue?

Tags: steam, steamworks, payment

I recently published a game on steam and I saw a deposit in my bank account with description of WPS-xxxxx (where the x's are a string of mostly numbers) Also, I do not live in the US

I've been looking around online to confirm whether this was steam sending me money for my game's sales but can't find anything. I need to confirm this fairly soon for personal reasons, so if any developers who've received money from steam can confirm or deny whether steam's payments have description starting with "WPS" I'd appreciate it.

I know this is an unusual question for this site so if someone can direct me to another place to ask I'd also appreciate the help, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Log into the portal and check**

> The Sales & Activations Reports portal provides a near real-time view into revenue, units, player counts, geographic breakdown, and other statistics related to your product.

https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/finance/payments_salesreporting